# 1 Peter 2:24; Did Peter express the whole Process of Crucifixion in terms of Lashing by whip?

Tags: jesus, 1-peter, crucifixion

1 Peter 2:24; DRB;

> 24 Who his own self bore our sins in his body upon the tree: that we, being dead to sins, should live to justice: **by whose stripes you were healed.**

Did Peter express the whole Process of **Crucifixion** in terms of **Lashing** by whip? Or Peter was expressing the whole suffering journey of the earthly life of Jesus?, Then it, (the Lashing), is symbolic?

Comment: Jesus' physical sufferings during crucifixion are not the subject of the Apostle's doctrine regarding remission of sins. What occurred in the three hours of darkness - from the sixth to the ninth hours - was the resolving of sins by the righteousness of God. (And the scourging administered by Pilate was _not_ a lawful part of the crucifixion : it was Pilate's attempt to outwardly punish Jesus in order to _avoid_ his death  by crucifxiion).

Answer (score 2):

The crucifixion of Jesus represented multiple fulfilment’s. His death *needed* to by account of the Mosaic Law - and although this *could* have been via any means, i.e. stoning - it couldn’t be via any other means other than crucifixion - because this was prophesied. But this to one side, because you are asking about the *lashing*, that is, the treatment *before* crucifixion.

This is a *part* of the whole picture, namely, suffering on account of ‘sin’ - ours! Not his!  ‘Sin’ is something done in the flesh - and the penalty for it is death, of the flesh. ‘Sin’ is punished *in the flesh*, so Jesus’s ‘flesh’ had to ‘pay the price’. And, that beating/lashing/etc had to result in, end with the ‘death’ of the flesh. Isaiah 53 graphically outlines this process!

There are multiple facets to this event, and this is just one, so does not present the total ‘picture’. But seeing you only asked about the … [snip] “*Process of Crucifixion in terms of Lashing*”, I’ll only answer *that part*.

The ‘lashing’ was *not* symbolic. It was necessary. It *had to be so* - because that is the judgement ‘sin’ demands.

Comment: You are mixing up sin and sins, particularlyi n your last paragraph.

Comment: @Nigel J The ‘sin’ I am referring to is that which one does ‘in the flesh’.

Comment: Sin dwells in the flesh of those born of Adam. When sin, within, brings forth deeds without : they are sins. He was effected sin and died, sin being destroyed in his death.  But prior to death, he suffered (in the three hours of darkness) in the body, bearing sins 'in his body on the tree' unto remission of sins. Redemption unto justification. The two should not be confused.

Comment: @NigelJ What we ‘*inherited*’ from Adam was a “sin” ‘*nature*’, that is, an unrighteous spirit [that is, one separated from God] - the ‘old man’. Man does *not* inherit ‘sin’ in his flesh. You have to ‘do’ something [wrong] with/using your ‘flesh’ in order to ‘get sin’ in your flesh - which we all end up doing. One, sin in the flesh’ was paid for via the beating/lashing/etc. The other [unrighteousness] is ‘fixed’ via being reborn - a ‘new creation’. I appreciate this view differs to your own, but seeing you asked a Q, I needed to explain my position.

Comment: _By one man sin entered into the world_ Rom 5:12. _By one man's disobedience many were made sinners_ Rom 5:19. _They that are in the flesh cannot please God_ Rom 8:5. 'Beating' the flesh does not drive sin out of it, nor does it atone for guilt. The righteousness of God is that which resolves these matters : when exerted upon His own Son, in humanity.

Answer (score 2):

Peter was matching the historic evens of the Crucifixion to Isa. 53.

> 4 οὗτος **τὰς ἁμαρτίας ἡμῶν φέρει** καὶ περὶ ἡμῶν ὀδυνᾶται, καὶ ἡμεῖς ἐλογισάμεθα αὐτὸν εἶναι ἐν πόνῳ καὶ ἐν πληγῇ καὶ ἐν κακώσει.  5 αὐτὸς δὲ ἐτραυματίσθη διὰ τὰς ἀνομίας ἡμῶν καὶ μεμαλάκισται διὰ τὰς ἁμαρτίας ἡμῶν, παιδεία εἰρήνης ἡμῶν ἐπʼ αὐτόν, **τῷ μώλωπι αὐτοῦ ἡμεῖς ἰάθημεν**.
> (Isa. 53:4–5, LXX)

> Surely he hath borne our griefs and carried our sorrows; and we, we did regard him stricken, smitten of God, and afflicted. 5  But he was wounded for our transgressions, he was bruised for our iniquities; the chastisement of our peace was upon him, and **with his stripes we are healed.** 6  All we like sheep have gone astray, we have turned every one to his own way; and Jehovah hath laid upon him the iniquity of us all.
> (Isa. 53:4–6, DRB)

> This one **carries our sins** and suffers pain for us, and we regarded him as one who is in difficulty, misfortune, and affliction. 5 But he was wounded because of our sins, and he became weakened because of our lawless acts. The discipline of our peace was upon him; **by his bruise we were healed**. 6 We all have been misled like sheep; each person was misled in his own path, and the Lord handed him over for our sins.
> --
> The Lexham English Septuagint (Second Edition, Isa. 53:4–6). (2020). Lexham Press.

> 24 ὃς **τὰς ἁμαρτίας ἡμῶν αὐτὸς ἀνήνεγκεν** ἐν τῷ σώματι αὐτοῦ ἐπὶ τὸ ξύλον, ἵνα ταῖς ἁμαρτίαις ἀπογενόμενοι τῇ δικαιοσύνῃ ⸁ζήσωμεν, οὗ **τῷ μώλωπι ἰάθητε.**
> (1 Pe 2:24, NA28)

> who himself bore our sins in his body on the tree, in order that, being dead to sins, we may live to righteousness: **by whose stripes ye have been healed**. 25  For ye were going astray as sheep, but have now returned to the shepherd and overseer of your souls.
> (1 Pet. 2:24–25, DRB)

Comment: Could you post the KJV or DRB translation to the Greek texts? And I need some details about your ideas.